# Execute Google App Script from content/background script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

I have made a chrome extension to run on GMail, in which I would like to trigger a Google app Script with a button I made. Can anyone tell me how to trigger/call Google script.

This is my script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var message = thread.getMessages()[0];
  var sub = message.getSubject();
  var body = message.getPlainBody();
  
  var text = /(Event)|(Party)/;
  result = sub.match(text);
  if(result == null) {
    result = body.match(text);
  }
  var q=0;
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if(labels[i] === "Events") {
      break;
    }
  else 
    q++;
  }
  if(q==labels.length)
    GmailApp.createLabel("Event")
    
  if(result != null)  {
    label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Event");
    label.addToThread(thread);
  }
  
  GMailApp.createLabel("Event");
  
  
}
```

My manifest.json file is below.

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "drc",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://mail.google.com/*",
        "http://mail.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js", "onclic.js"],
      "css": ["drpdwn.css"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Append Test Text"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["logo.png", "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://mail.google.com/*",
    "http://mail.google.com/* ",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.*"
  ]
}
```

Now whenever a user install my extention, google script function should also be installed automatically, How do I do that.

Comment: Can you show your manifest.json?

Comment: Use the Apps Script API if you need user-level authentication, or if it's just for you, deploy your webapp anonymously, run it as you, and use the web app links.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `doPost()` or `doGet()` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#doget_and_dopost) and execute your Google Apps Script.